# Using OpenCV with libtiff

Tags: opencv, tiff, multipage

I am trying to work with libtiff and opencv together.  I installed the opencv precompiled libraries and found that the libtiff library is part of the installation, however, I was not able to use any libtiff function (I am trying to read a multipage tiff file but opencv does not support it).  So, I installed the stand-alone libtiff libraries (from libtiff.org) in a separate folder and wrote a function to read the multipage tiff file, but now I cannot combine the opencv program with the libtiff program since there is a clash between the stand-alone libtiff libraries and the opencv libtiff libraries.

Thx

PS My environment:  Windows 7 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2012

Comment: You should be able to link with OpenCV's version of libtiff, can you give details about why you couldn't do this?

Comment: After I wrote the opencv program, I added the header : #include <tiffio.h> and had no problem with compilation and linking.  However, then I wanted to add some libtiff-related functions so I added the lines: TIFF *image;
image = TIFFOpen("testImg.tiff", "r"); and started to get a bunch of link errors.  When I wrote the same two lines in a separate program using the original stand-alone libtiff libraries, I had no problem.